# This iPhone is running iOS 12.0 (16A366), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios12

I am using Xcode (Version 9.0 (9A235)), and when I tried to run my app on my iPhone, I am getting this error.

> This iPhone is running iOS 12.0 (16A366), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

I can't update my Xcode due to an incompatible version of macOS.
Any other solution?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use xcode 10 for ios version 12.0.

Answer (score 1):

Download files based in your iPhone Model [IN HERE](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/OTA_Updates/iPhone/12.0)

1 - Open directory:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

3 - Create new folder "12.0 (16A366)" depends on what exactly are you missing

4 - Paste the OTA Files Uncompressed

6 - Restart Xcode

Answer (score 0):

iOS 12 is only supported by the beta of Xcode 10 or higher.
If you want to use your iPhone 8 with this iOS version (NOT RECOMMENDED) with your Xcode 9.4 you can try to download the last beta of Xcode 10 and after connecting the iPhone to the mac go to this folder:

**/Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport**

You can see the iOS version folder of the iPhone, copy and past it to the same location in your Xcode 9.4 folder.
After this you should be able to deploy to your iPhone 8.

Answer (score 0):

Download (16A366) file from this link and paste at /Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

[Link to Download file (16A366)](https://files.fm/u/j94hzaqc)

Comment: and restart XCode

Comment: You should have uploaded this to github. The file is removed.