# This iPhone XS Max is running iOS 12.1 (16B92), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode

This iPhone XS Max is running iOS 12.1 (**16B92**), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

Comment: Update your Xcode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This iPhone is running iOS 12.0 (16A366), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575751/this-iphone-is-running-ios-12-0-16a366-which-may-not-be-supported-by-this-ver)

Answer (score 0):

Update your Xcode. You did not specify the Xcode version so I can only assume.

**If you have Xcode 9:**

Update your Xcode version. If you macOS is incompatible please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575751/this-iphone-is-running-ios-12-0-16a366-which-may-not-be-supported-by-this-ver)

**If you have Xcode 10:**

Please make sure you have the latest version of Xcode from [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com)